# Storing image in subfolder of AWS S3 in scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3

I have a bucket "test" in amazon AWS S3 and in that bucket their is another subfolder i.e, "sub_test" now i want to save images in "sub_test" folder. Is their any way to do that??
Any idea will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      //Creating object push request
      var putObj:PutObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, "fooDir/"+imageName+".png", imageStream, objMetaData)
      //Providing object with public read-only permission
      //putObj.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead) , depends upon your need
      //Pushing the object
      amazonS3Client.putObject(putObj)
```